# ManyToOne column in embeddable class

Tags: java, jpa, toplink

I have two entities who embed (`@Embedded`) the Adress embeddable. In the Adress class there is a property who points to an entity Location. In the Adress class I put `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn(...)` annotations above it. Now I get this error:

> Exception Description: The table
>   [persons] is not present in this
>   descriptor. Descriptor:
>   RelationalDescriptor(com.wordpress.aiids.voeder.model.Location
>   --> [DatabaseTable(locations)])

It's the `@JoinColumn` annotation that causes the trouble:

```
@ManyToOne
//@JoinColumn(name = "gemeente", referencedColumnName = "gemeente", nullable = false)
private Gemeente gemeente;
```

Here's the full code of the embbedable class.

http://aiids.pastebin.com/G1sijNBL

Do I do something wrong by putting those annotations there or what's the cause of this error?

**SOLUTION!**

The solution is that the `referencedColumnName` must point to the Primary Key of the Entity Gemeente which was "postcode" and not "gemeente".

Comment: instead of explaining your code, why not show it?

Comment: You understand Dutch? I'll show you where the problem is. *updated*